# Can I use the Service "Trello" as Task-Repository with Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, trello

i want to use "Trello.com" as Task-Repository on Netbeans but I cant find any tutorial or helping hand on google. So I ended up asking here if someone knows if it is even possible to do so.

Hopefully,
Flaflo

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Trello api](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference)?

Comment: But how do implement it for using it in netbeans. I saw the support in intellij and eclipse

Comment: Did you read the docs at Trello?